# How to Style Specific Element On Hover With CSS?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hyperlink, hover

This question is for http://chameleonwebsolutions.com. I need it so that when you hover over the social media links, their color changes to a darker green (#72984a). I tried:

```
.site-header .fa a:hover {
color: #72984a !important;
}

.fa .fa-facebook-square a:hover {
color:#72984a !important;
}

.social-icons a:hover {
color:#72984a !important;
}

.logo .mobile-social-icons .hidden-tablet a:hover {
color:#72984a !important;
}

.social-icons .hidden-mobile .responsive-header-gutter a:hover {
color: #72984a !important;
}
```

In the stylesheet but none of them are showing up in the inspector. I would try just a:hover in the stylesheet (no class before it) but then of course that would apply to all of the hyperlinks. How can I style only the social media links when you hover over them? Thanks!

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The squares are inside the `<a>` tags, not the other way around like you're trying to do. Your CSS `.fa a:hover` applies to `<a>` inside the `.fa` which is the class for the squares.

The problem is that the green color is applied to the squares `<i>` not the `<a>`. I cannot test your code, but try this:

```
.social-icons i:hover {
    color: #72984a;
}
```

Or of course this is the same but using class selector instead of tag:

```
.social-icons .fa:hover {
    color: #72984a;
}
```

However, if you want to follow the exiting CSS way, use this:

```
.site-header .fa:hover {
    color: #72984a;
}
```

In all cases, always try to apply the correct styles and avoid using `!important`.

Comment: Didn't know you could style :hover state of an i link - it worked, thank you!